# reverse engineer mysql database to create django app

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

I basically want to take an existing mysql database structure created and used by a php app (codeigniter framework) and reverse engineer it to a django app.  is there some tool to do this? south migrations maybe?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Create a project, and point your settings @ your database

Then run

`./manage.py inspectdb`

This will print out a python models file for the DB you're pointing at

You can output this to a file by doing something like

`./manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

And then you can move the file to the most suitable location, and edit it as needed.

Comment: Good answer. Chapter 18 of the Django Book has further details on using inspectdb to integrate existing databases - http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18/

Comment: Great this is what i wanted exactly!, also going to generate the er diagram based on this using graphviz & django_extensions

Comment: Make sure you check the generated `model.py` carefully!  In particular lengths of `CharField`s and missing `ForeignKey`s was the problem cases last time I used it.  It saved many hours of making the `model.py` by hand though.