# MySQL schema to Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a handy way to translate a MySQL schema to a Django model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse engineer mysql database to create django app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545714/reverse-engineer-mysql-database-to-create-django-app)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this command will do exactly what it says on the tin

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Comment: Perfect!  How did I ever not see this before?  Thanks!

Comment: Wow! I somehow cleverly assumed this just dumped the defined models for a Django instance. Now, if it was called `introspectdb`? RTFCH, noted :D!