# Django - importing existing database

Tags: django

I'm wondering how to import an existing sqlite3 database and all it's entries into a new Django project. 
Lets say for example my existing database is called mydatab.db containing a table called 'cars' which has the columns 'name', 'year' and 'owner'. All the columns are text.
All examples I have found are for creating new databases and manually entering data.

Thanks

Comment: You should learn about `./manage.py inspectdb` command. See [reverse engineer mysql database to create django app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545714/reverse-engineer-mysql-database-to-create-django-app)

Comment: Duplicated. There is a good answer at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545714/reverse-engineer-mysql-database-to-create-django-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reverse engineer mysql database to create django app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545714/reverse-engineer-mysql-database-to-create-django-app)