# Loading data from a (MySQL) database into Django without models

Tags: python, mysql, django

Is it possible to load data from a (in this case MySQL) table to be used in Django without the need for a model to be present?

I'm working on a site, which, for one aspect makes use of a table of data which has been bought from a third party. The columns of interest are likely to remain stable, however the structure of the table could change with subsequent updates to the data set. The table is also massive (in terms of columns) - so I'm not keen on typing out each field in the model one-by-one. I'd also like to leave the table intact - so coming up with a model which represents the set of columns I am interested in is not really an ideal solution.

Ideally, I want to have this table in a database somewhere (possibly separate to the main site database) and access its contents directly using SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always execute raw SQL directly against the database: see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: Thanks - that was the solution that I was expecting to go for. I was just trying to see whether there was another way.

Since posting this question, I have come across [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545714/reverse-engineer-mysql-database-to-create-django-app) on SO which I think may help me achieve what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is one feature called  `inspectdb` in **Django**. for legacy databases like MySQL , it creates models automatically by inspecting your db tables. it stored in our app files as **models.py**. so we don't need to type all column manually.But read the documentation carefully before creating the models because it may affect the DB data ...i hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: That's the solution I referenced in my comment on the accepted answer. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use any SQL library available for Python. For example : http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

You have just then to connect to your database, perform your request and use the datas at your will. I think you can't use Django without their model system, but nothing prevents you from using another library for this in parallel.

Comment: See Daniel Roseman's answer, better solution. I missed this part when checking the documentation.